# Make edges avoid vertices in mxGraph?

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

I have an mxGraph, and my edges use an OrthoConnect style so that the arrows of the edges correctly point to the vertex. I found with other styles, they remained horizontal even when connecting to the top and bottom of a vertex. The OrthoConnect lets arrows point correctly.

Anyway, I have two edges coming out of one vertex, going to two different vertices. However, one edge goes right through a vertex:

[image]

Ideally, this would would branch down around where the first arrow is if not a little before and avoid that vertex.

Is there anyway to control this and have edges avoid vertices.

I end up placing my edges behind the vertices, so this looks confusing as edges appear to be coming from vertices they are not supposed to be coming from.